# How do I format pandas timestamp or day_name() function to DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm new to python and pandas, so thank you all for helping me in advance.

I lived in the UK, so I use the DD/MM/YYYY format, and I've checked, the region for my PC is also in the format of DD/MM/YYYY in the system.

However when I wrote the following:

```
def mock_day_of_week():
    # return Monday
    temp = pd.Timestamp("15/11/2021")
    print(temp.day_name())

mock_day_of_week()


def mock_day_of_week1():
    # return Monday too
    temp = pd.Timestamp("11/15/2021")
    print(temp.day_name())

mock_day_of_week1()
```

Regardless if it's DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY, they both return Monday, so that's great. With the exception that the DD/MM/YYYY also return this:

> sys:1: UserWarning: Parsing '15/11/2021' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide
> format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing.

However, when I test the following functions:

```
def mock_day_of_week3():
    # should return Sunday for 12th June 2022, but return as Tuesday for 6th December 2022 instead
    temp = pd.Timestamp("12/6/2022")
    print(temp.day_name())

mock_day_of_week3()


def mock_day_of_week4():
    # should return Friday for 6th May 2022 but return as Sunday for 5th June 2022 instead
    temp = pd.Timestamp("06/05/2022")
    print(temp.day_name())

mock_day_of_week4()
```

The Timestamp function start reading as MM/DD/YYYY instead.

What is the correct format that I need to add to the argument so that it force the Timestamp to recognise DD/MM/YYYY format instead.

I've tried the suggested:

```
temp = pd.Timestamp("06/05/2022", infer_datetime_format=True)
print(temp.day_name())
```

but this gives an error of:

> File "pandas_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx", line 1248, in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.**new** TypeError: **new**()
> got an unexpected keyword argument 'infer_datetime_format'

I'm stump, thanks in advance for any input on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest way is to specify them as integers via named arguments:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(day=12, month=6, year=2022)
```

You can also use `dayfirst` from [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to remove ambiguity on whether month or days are first:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('12/6/2022', dayfirst=True)
```

Finally, you may also provide a `format`:

```
pd.to_datetime('12/6/2022', format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Please give the priority to the second option `dayfirst=True` because it's the simplest way :)

Comment: My answer duplicates your 2nd and 3rd options (slow typing ...)

Answer (score 0):

add tz parameter with your timezone

```
temp = pd.Timestamp("05/06/2022", tz='Europe/London')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is:

> What is the correct format that I need to add to the argument so that it force the Timestamp to recognise DD/MM/YYYY format?

One way to be very explicit about this is the following:

```py
    temp = pd.to_datetime("12/6/2021", format="%d/%m/%Y")
    print(temp.month_name())
```

Alternatively, you can to this:

```py
    temp = pd.to_datetime("12/6/2021", dayfirst=True)
    print(temp.month_name())
```

Comment: note that `pd.Timestamp()` here is redundant, because `pd.to_datetime` already returns a `pd.Timestamp` ;)

Comment: Yep, good point. Corrected.

Comment: @rafaelc Although, for completeness, I note that the [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) docs indicate that return type may be `datetime.datetime` as a "fallback in case of unsuccessful timezone or out-of-range timestamp parsing". But if the fallback is required, a call to `pd.Timestamp()` (which uses utc instead of local time by default) probably won't be "successful" either.

Comment: Oh right, that's a good point

Comment: @M C Do you need any additional help with this question?